# laravel One to one relation with pivot table

Tags: many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.1, one-to-one

hi Need some suggestions
I have three table

**personal_details**
**vacancies**

and a pivot table

**personal_detail_vacancy**

pivot table contains vacancy_id and the personal_detail_id (user who applied for a open vacancy) my problem is sending some personal_detail_id to a hotlists for a particular vacancy. so should i add status field in pivot table or create a hotlists table with one-to-one relation with pivot table . which one is better please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a 'hotlist' is, but if you need to set a flag on each record in the pivot table, you can create a boolean `status` column and access it like this:

```
$person = PersonalDetails::find(1);

foreach ($person->vacancies as $vacancy)
{
    echo $vacancy->pivot->status;
}
```

Comment: actually hotlist is selection of some users for interview from the pivot table. yes I tried putting status field in pivot table but when I tried to update the status value by using sync the unselected id automatically deleted from pivot table.

Comment: That's actually how sync() is supposed to work. It replaces the pivot relationships for that object with only what your provide in the sync() array. Sounds like you want to use attach() which adds an additional record to a pivot table and doesn't destroy any existing ones. Or if you're going to use sync, make sure the array you pass in contains all the existing pivot relationships for that record. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: yes but is there any other way ? just to change the extra field value of the selected id and prevent other from delete. attach() will add a new row but I need to update a existing record

Comment: Yes, if you're looking to update that `status` record, you can use something like this: `PersonalDetails::find(1)->vacancies()->updateExistingPivot($vacancy_id, ['status'=>1]);`.  You can take a look at that method here: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_updateExistingPivot

Comment: thanks but i solved the problem by making second parameter of sync() to false $model->relation()->sync([$related->id => [ 'state' => 1] ], false);

Comment: Sure that works too!  If my first response answered your original posted question, then please mark it as correct! :)